# Convert Date to Hex String using Swift (BLE)

Tags: swift, date, datetime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to send my current time to BLE device, but I am strugling to understand, how I can get Hex string representation of my current time.

I need to convert Date() to Unix hexadecimal timestamp like this 61B06270 or array of UInt8.

Comment: What is `61B06270` supposed to be? You mean convert a Timestamp (Double) into Data? Convert a String Date into Data with UTF8 encoding? What's the documentation?

Comment: Most likely you don't want a hex string. That's just how it's documented and how a debugger would should it. More likely, it's a specific binary format your BLE device is expecting. In order to help you, you need to provide more information about the format. "something like this" won't do.

Comment: Unix hexadecimal timestamp in UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I was looking for:

```
let dateInt = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let dateHex = String(dateInt, radix: 16, uppercase: true)
print(dateHex)
```

Now dateHex could be devided on bites and sent to BLE device